# Windows server 2022 - Cannot extend C: partition

Tags: windows, windows-server-2022

I'm trying to extend my C: partition (I have 10 GB Unallocated), but the extend option is grayed out :

[Disk Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meNRP.png)

Same results with diskpart command : There is not enough usable free space on specified disk(s) to extend the volume.

And the extend failed with the File and Storage Services (Server Manager\File and Storage Services\Volumes\Disks) :

[File and Storage Services Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGRT5.png)

Any idea about this issue ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extent must be contiguous.

You may be able to use a partition tool like GParted to move the recovery partition to where it should be, at the beginning of the disk.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped that I reduced the size of the system drive C by 1 MB and after that the 'extend option' was displayed and I was able to extend the 30 GB.

The extend option is only displayed if the free space on the system drive is directly behind the allocated area. Reducing the size by 1MB obviously results in a change.